# Swift 3 NSMutableURLRequest second call fail

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, nsmutableurlrequest

at all, I created a function that sends a "GET" request, to a amazon aws server, and gets a response in JSON, and then these data are placed in a table. When I first call this data, everything works perfectly, but when I get back to the home screen and open the view again with the table, the same function fails, returning an incorrect header error, even though it worked for the first time, I attach the code:

Function:

```
func getData(url:String, complete: @escaping ([Int:Any]) -> Void) {
    var array: [Int:Any] = [:]
    let headers = [
        "authorization": "Bearer codeBearer",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]
    print(headers)
    print(url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!) // errore
        } else {
            let input = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)?.data(using: .utf8) // json
            let json = try! JSON(data: input!)
            print(json)
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                let num = subJson["index"].int
                if( num != nil ){
                    array[num!] = subJson
                }
            }
            session.invalidateAndCancel()
            complete(array)
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

View:

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

func reload(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if( idCell == "cell" ){
        fun.getData(url: fun.request("/v1/media", test: true), complete: { success in
            self.array = success
            self.reload()
        })
    }else{
        fun.getData(url: fun.request("/v1/banner", test: true), complete: { success in
            self.array = success
            self.reload()
        })
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    {
  "message" : "'codeBearer' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer codeBearer'."
}
```

If I try to send the request through the curl, it works every time, while here only works the first time I perform the function, but if I close and reopen the application it works again for the first time, tips on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To cleanup your session invoke below.

```
session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

Comment: Ok then can't you store your data into one variable?. So that second time you do not need to make the call again? Is that make sense??

Comment: I will usually save the data in a variable, but from time to time I will need to update the data (as it will change quickly) so I will be able to retrieve the data

Comment: ok so can you change this "Bearer codeBearer" to that "Bearer-codeBearer". Just for testing if it works?

Comment: If I change the code, inserting the "-" request fails because the token bearer is not correct

Comment: Are you calling this invalidateAndCancel()?? When your session task is finished? If not then try calling this

Comment: We call this in our project when session task finished

Comment: I entered "session.invalidateAndCancel()" but it does the same mistake

Comment: I put it before "complete(array)"

Comment: Then am sorry issue looks something different

Answer (score 0):

I Know this answer is very late, but i faced this same issue when consuming **SOAP web service**.

**You should use `ephemeral` session** on a SOAP service call when you are invoking it like a REST service call.

Example Code

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
```

Here is the documentation form apple about various types of URL Sessions

1. A **`default`** session behaves much like the shared session, but allows
   more configuration, and allows you to obtain data incrementally with
   a delegate.
2. **`Ephemeral`** sessions are similar to shared sessions, but don’t write
       caches, cookies, or credentials to disk.
3. **`Background`** sessions let you perform uploads and downloads of content
   in the background while your app isn't running.